# Make POST request to zendesk api using google apps-script

Tags: google-apps-script, zendesk-api

I want to make a POST request to the zendesk api which will create zendesk tickets from google sheets every time a google form is submitted.

My problem is, my authentication keeps failing.

I have confirmed my api token is valid using Curl and python script.

Here is a simple version of my apps-script code:

```
function onSubmit(e){      
  var subject = 'Test ticket';
  var body = 'test ticket was successful!';
  var data = {'ticket': {'subject': subject, 'comment': {'body': body}}};
  var url = 'https://mydomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json';
  var user = 'myemail@email.com/token:';
  var pwd = 'MY_SECRET_API_KEY';

  options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'headers': {
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'Authorization':  'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(user + pwd);
    },
    'data' : JSON.stringify(data)
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

**Modified Apps script code**

```
function onSubmit(e){
  var subject = 'Test ticket';
  var body = 'test ticket was successful!';
  var data = {'ticket': {'subject': subject, 'comment': {'body': body}}};      
  var url = 'https://mydomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json';
  var user = 'myemail@email.com/token';
  var pwd = 'MY_SECRET_API_KEY';
  var options = {
      'method' : 'post',
      'headers': {
        'Authorization': "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + pwd)
      },
      'payload' : JSON.stringify(data),
      'contentType': 'application/json',
      'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

Response:
`401`
`{"error":"Couldn't authenticate you"}`

My python script that works:

```
import json
import requests

subject = 'This is a test!'
body = 'Testing api calls.'
data = {'ticket': {'subject': subject, 'comment': {'body': body}}}
payload = json.dumps(data)
url = 'https://mydomain.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets.json'
user = 'myemail@email.com/token'
pwd = 'MY_SECRET_API_KEY'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

response = requests.post(url, data=payload, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers)

if response.status_code != 201:
    print('Status:', response.status_code, payload, 'Problem with the request. Exiting.')
    exit()

print('Successfully created the ticket.')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

Please modify `options` as follows.

- When you use `contentType`, please put it to outside of `headers`.

  - When you use `Content-Type`, please put it in the `headers`.
- Modify from `data` to `payload`.

#### Modified script:

```
var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'headers': {
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + pwd), // Modified
  },
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
};
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that your python script works fine.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params)

If this didn't work, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Response is still returning a 401, 'Couldn't authenticate you'.

Comment: @Casey Gov I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. I have forgot about the basic authorization. So I modified and updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? I have a question for your script. In your python script, you use ``user = 'myemail@email.com/token'``. But in your GAS, you use ``user = 'myemail@email.com/token:'``. Is this difference related to the issue?

Comment: Thank you for your follow up. Auth is still failing unfortunately. @Tanaike

Comment: @Casey Gov I'm really sorry for the inconvenience. In your question, you say that your python script works. In this modified GAS script, I confirmed that the request is the same with that of your python script. So can you show your latest GAS script? I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have added the modified script to the question above. Note I have also confirmed with zendesk, my API token is still valid. My python script still creates zendesk tickets successfully,

Comment: @Casey Gov I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I could confirm that the request body of your python and Google Apps Script is the same. So is there possibility that the URL cannot be accessed from Google domain? I was worry about this situation.